# I want to convert some data to pivot in SQL Server with join and dynamic

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, join, pivot-table

[image]

The table, at last, is my target.

This is my demo database

```
create database pvtestDb;
go

use pvtestDb;
go

create table custTransaction
(
    id int,
    custNum int,
    value nvarchar(50)
)
go

create table customers
(
    id int,
    custName nvarchar(50)
)

insert into Customers(id, custName) 
values (1, 'aaa'), (2, 'bbb'), (3, 'ccc'), (4, 'ddd'), 
       (5, 'eee'), (6, 'fff'), (7, 'ggg'), (8, 'hhh'), (9, 'iii')

insert into custTransaction (id, custNum, value) 
values (1, 3, 'a'), (1, 4, 'b'), (1, 5, 'c'),
       (2, 3, 'd'), (2, 4, 'e'), (2, 6, 'f'),
       (3, 3, 'g'), (3, 8, 'h'), (3, 9, 'i')

select * from customers
select * from custTransaction


select custName, custNum, value 
from customers
join custTransaction on custTransaction.id = customers.id
```

I tried code like this but not worked at all

```
SELECT 
    custNum, [a], [b], [c], [d]  
FROM
    customers
JOIN
    custTransaction ON custTransaction.id = customers.id
PIVOT
    (COUNT([custName]) 
     FOR [custName] IN ([a], [b], [c], [d])) AS p
```

I need to join between the two tables in first.

Any hints would be appreciated as I am stuck with this situation

Comment: the two answers are applicable 
for derived table answer this is the way to write the solution in my case 

   select
        id, [aaa], [bbb], [ccc], [ddd] 
    from (
        select
            ct.id, c.custName, ct.value
        from 
            customers c
            join custTransaction ct on ct.custNum = c.id
    ) t
    pivot (
        max(value) for custName in ([aaa], [bbb], [ccc], [ddd] )
    ) p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's approach with dynamic SQL

```
declare @customers varchar(8000)
declare @sql varchar(8000)

select @customers = stuff((
    select ',' + quotename(custName)
    from customers
    for xml path('')
), 1, 1, '')

set @sql = 'select
        id, ' + @customers + '
    from (
        select
            ct.id, c.custName, ct.value
        from 
            customers c
            join custTransaction ct on ct.custNum = c.id
    ) t
    pivot (
        max(value) for custName in (' + @customers + ')
    ) p'

exec (@sql)
```

Output

```
id  aaa     bbb     ccc   ddd   eee   fff   ggg     hhh     iii
----------------------------------------------------------------
1   NULL    NULL    a     b     c     NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    d     e     NULL  f     NULL    NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL    g     NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    h       i
```